# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' in python code

Tags: python

I have the following line of code that opens a document called document.txt that looks somewhat like this.

3 4 5 6 6

3 2 8 9

4 6

```
with open('document.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
                farray = [int(i) for i in line.split(" ")]
                lArray.append(farray)
```

but I'm getting the following error.

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

is there something obvious here that I'm missing?

Comment: Try check out if you have a blank string, this can be the reason of your exception

Comment: To debug, add `print(line.split(" "))` before the crash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing that there's a blank line at the end of the file. This, when stripped, becomes an empty string, which cannot be parsed as an int.

Deleting the blank line will make this work, but you can think of this as an exercise in defensive programming. As one of my favorite professors once told me, "a good programmer is someone who looks both ways before crossing a one-way street".

Comment: Yes! That was the issue. Thanks tons!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You might have to replace the line skip which is something like this in python

```
\n
```

If I were you my code would be:

```
f = open('document.txt','r')
temp = f.readlines()
array = []
for i in temp:
    i = i.replace("\n","")
    i = i.split(" ")
    for x in range(len(i)):
        i[x] = int(i)
    array.append(i)
```

Comment: In general, the python style is to iterate over the objects in a list directly, not via their index. "For each item in the list, do something to the item" is preferable to "For each number i in the list of numbers from zero to the count of items in the list, look up the item indexed by i and do something to that number".

Answer (score 1):

I have also gone through this problem. The simple thing you can do is either use
`strip()` method or `replace()` method.

Hope this will help you to find the answer.